# Remove shortcode in SQL database

Tags: sql, shortcode

I'm trying to find this shortcode in wordpress posts

```
[su_quote][/su_quote]
[su_divider top="no" style="dotted" divider_color="#c9c9c9"]
```

and replace with nothing (only want to remove it)

I use this code in SQL:

```
update wp_posts set post_content =
replace(post_content,
        '[su_quote][/su_quote][su_divider top="no" style="dotted" divider_color="#c9c9c9"]',
        '');
```

but the result is 0 changes.

Do you have some suggestion to let it work?

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you `select` rows with your replace text using a `where like` criteria?

Comment: I.e.`select * from wp_posts  where post_content <> replace(post_content,
        '[su_quote][/su_quote...`

Comment: You need to do some data analysis. Maybe the posts are stored with a different string. Try: SELECT * FROM WP_POSTS WHERE post_content like '%su_quote%';